# Lepton and hadron interaction would be weak or strong?

Tags: particle-physics

For example an electron neutrino interacting with a neutron creates a proton and an electron. Would this interaction be weak or strong? I already understand hadron-hadron interactions are strong and lepton-lepton interactions are weak. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your proposed reaction violates charge conservation I guess :)

Comment: Was meant to write neutron in the first part instead of proton :)

Comment: You can just edit your question to make the desired correction. 

Comment: *If only* you had written down the definitions of "lepton" and "hadron"....

Answer (score 1):

This would be a weak interaction. Leptons cannot feel strong interactions, thus any interaction is not strong that involves leptons.

Furthermore, neutrinos can ONLY interact via weak interaction.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Was a bit confusing for me as I thought as a proton was produced it would be strong.

Comment: Protons are made from quarks. You really should look at this reaction as a neutrino interacting with a quark, rather than a proton, because proton cannot be considered point-like. Quark feels all the forces  hence can interact via any of them